# why does auto deduce lvalue reference when using auto&&it=--vec.end(),is it UB?

Tags: c++, c++11

See the code snippet below:

```
#include<vector>
using std::vector;
int main()
{
  vector<int> a;
  auto &&it=--a.end();//what?the hint tell me it deduces a lvalue reference type!
}
```

We all know that a self-defined class with `operator --` returns a **xvalue** when the operand itself is a rvalue, like `--Myclass()`. Obviously `Myclass()` is **prvalue**, so the return value of `--Myclass()` should also be **rvalue**(prcisely,xvalue) ,too.
from [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

> a.m, the member of object expression, where a is an rvalue and m is a non-static data member of non-reference type;

So why does the `auto` deduce lvalue reference in this circumstance?
What's more,**the code snippet could be compiled without any error!**

**Why could a rvalue be binded to a lvalue reference?**

And I've come across a confusing error(Not the same as the code snippet above,I'm sure the vector is not empty):Later when I use the `it`,  **segment fault** happens!

[The code that causes **segment fault**](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5BSTwW2Ssv/) (in the last three lines) This code is the answer for a Chinese online testing [PAT](https://www.patest.cn/contests/pat-a-practise/1068),when I submit the answer, it arouses segment fault.

Is it **undefined behavior** to use lvalue reference to bind a `--Myclass()` ,and use it later?

Comment: Your obvious assumption is wrong.

Comment: --a returns a lvalue whereas a-- returns a rvalue

Comment: Are you asking "why do I need to add &&", or are you saying "the && doesn't work"?

Comment: It is a-- that returns an rvalue.

Comment: @Light But later when I use the `it`,  ** segment fault**  happens!

Comment: @bigxiao Because the vector is empty. Edit: maybe in your case it wasn't, but the iterator was invalidated another way, but who knows... There is no MCVE.

Comment: @LogicStuff Sorry ,but what does MCVE mean?

Comment: @LogicStuff Why is the assumption wront? I think the `Myclass()` is rvalue,and all its member function returns xvalue,which is also rvalue.

Comment: Why not just keep it by value?? `auto it=--a.end();`.

Comment: @rustyx To prevent copying,mabe.

Comment: @bigxiao copy elision is very likely to apply to any copy that you could have avoided with a reference in this case. Besides, iterators are typically *very* fast to copy.

Comment: @bigxiao and MCVE is this: [mcve]

Comment: Beware premature optimization; in fact, a vector's iterator is just a pointer. Accessing one by reference can end up with a pointer to a pointer **and** it has to be put in memory just so there is an address of it. Remove the reference and the whole iterator object will fit in one register.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> We all know that a self-defined class with `operator --` returns a rvalue when we write somethin like `--Myclass()`

No, that's not something we know. Technically, a user defined prefix decrement operator can return either an object, or a reference. In practice, the prefix decrement operator typically returns an lvalue reference.

> Obviously `Myclass()` is prvalue, so the return value of `--Myclass()` should also be prvalue ,too.

That's not how value categories propagate. You can call a function on a prvalue, and the function can return an lvalue (possibly to `*this`).

> So why does the auto deduce lvalue reference in this circumstance?

Because the decrement operator of the iterator returns an lvalue reference.

---

Use `auto it` to fix the problem.

---

> Is it undefined behavior to use lvalue reference to bind a `--Myclass()` ,and use it later?

Depends on how `Myclass::operator--()` is declared. If it returns an lvalue reference, then that is UB. If it returns an object, then there is no UB. It is possible to provide both variants overloaded by ref-qualifier.

Comment: I've re-edited the question to state my problem more clearly.I know that the `operator --`  returns lvalue reference in most cases.But in this case, it's rvalue.

Comment: @bigxiao what is an xrvalue (mentioned in the edited question)?

Comment: OK,I forget that the `return *this` is lvalue,no matter the object itself is a rvalue or not.But is it **undefined behavior** to use lvalue reference to bind a `--Myclass()` ,and use it later?

Comment: Why does the **stdlib** does not use a **ref qualifier** here? Because `--vec.end()` here is very confusing.

Comment: @bigxiao well, iterators have existed since before ref qualifiers. I'm not sure why the overloads weren't introduced along with ref qualifiers in C++11. Perhaps they weren't considered, or maybe there is a problem with backwards compatibility. I'm just guessing.

Comment: @bigxiao figured out a backward incompatibility: If standard iterators were guaranteed to overload operators by ref-qualifier, then a pointer couldn't be used as an iterator for vector or string (because pointer operations are built-in). Some implementations do use a pointer.

Answer (score -6):

This is an ["universal reference"](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers). The variable is not an rvalue reference, but an lvalue into which the rvalue is moved. This is necessary because a reference would not extend the life time of the temporary object.

Comment: BTW ,nowadays it's called "forwarding reference" ,because there is nothing universal about it ,a temporary misnomer.

Comment: You don't move into references.

Comment: I did not claim anything would be moved into a reference. The linked article uses auto&& in the same way.

Comment: *"The variable is not an rvalue reference, but an lvalue into which the rvalue is moved."* What variable do you mean then?

Comment: The "it" variable is not a reference, but an lvalue into which the temporary is moved.

Comment: @Erlkoenig `it` is a reference, and here is [the proof](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76ab1e81bb983024).

Comment: Okay, i mistakenly assumed the --operator would return a rvalue, like the OP did, and explained why the value category doesn't propagate.

Comment: In any case it would remain a reference. If `--` returned an rvalue, it would be an rvalue reference.

Comment: Interesting, and rvalue references can extend the life time of the temporary object, even though non-const lvalue ones can not?

Comment: It appears that I mixed the whole thing up with the deduced type. Like in "template <typename T> void f(T&&)" the "T" becomes the actual value type, not a reference type, when an rvalue is passed to the function.